# .htaccess file content to allow access to one file and one folder only

Tags: apache, .htaccess

For the below files and folder structure

```
beta
   folder1
   folder2
   folder3
   file1.php
   file2.php
```

I need to restrict access to all files and folders **with the exception of *folder2* and *file2.php*. only**.

My *.htaccess* file currently looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/folder2%$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/file2.php
RewriteRule $ /beta/file2.php [R=302,L]
```

The above does work in one system, but not from other system.

Can you point out what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: is that `%` sign in your condition a typo? And is this htaccess file in your beta directory?

Comment: Thanks Jon for looking into this. Well, no its not. I saw an example in another site. Yes, this resides in the beta directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your rules around so that you let the 2 folders pass through then redirect everything to file2:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /beta/
RewriteRule ^file2\.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^folder2 - [L]
RewriteRule ^ file2.php [L,R=302]
```

The error you were getting is probably from the `%` that you had in your condition.

If you want to outright forbid access to anything else, you can change the last rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

---

> If you dont mind can you please explain each line ?

The `RewriteBase` directive lets the rewrite engine know that relative paths have a URI-base of `/beta/`. So all of the files/pathnames that don't start with a `/` will automatically have that base.

The next two rules simply matches against the URI and does a "pass through" using the `-` character, which means, "don't do anything". So when you request `/folder2` or `/file2.php`, the rewrite engine does nothing and lets the request through as if nothing happened. But if the request is anything else, the first 2 rules won't match and the last rule will match because the regex is `^`, which matches everything. The target of that rule redirects everything to `/beta/file2.php` (because of the base).

The forbidden rule with the `F` flag in the square brackets is the same thing, If the request isn't for the folder2 or file2.php, then that rule will match it (`^`) and it passes it through (`-`) but the `F` flag makes it return a "403 Forbidden" instead of serving whatever the request was for.

Comment: Thanks Jon, this worked perfectly fine. Wow. If you dont mind can you please explain each line ? My knowledge in this area is very poor.

Comment: Brilliant.That was very helpful. Thanks again Jon for taking out time to explain. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `REQUEST_FILENAME` insted of `REQUEST_URI` I hope this will help

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/folder2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/file2.php
RewriteRule $ /file2.php [R=302,L]
```